Azure Container apps Authentication whitelist swagger endpoint
When enabling Authentication for an API in Azure Container Apps is there a way to whitelist the swagger endpoint so it can be called without Authentication token being present?

direct endpoint-based whitelisting in the authentication settings isn't natively supported through Azure's configuration, you can manage this at the application level by implementing conditional authentication within your application code

Ok I will accept this answer if you turn comment to answer

As discussed, direct endpoint-based whitelisting in the authentication settings isn't natively supported through Azure's configuration,
Rather configure your Azure Container App to use Microsoft identity for authentication and allowed unauthenticated requests. This setup lets you handle requests that don't meet the authentication criteria within your application, allowing you to specify which endpoints, such as your Swagger UI, can be accessed without authentication.


Now, you'll need to implement the logic in your application code to properly manage both authenticated and unauthenticated requests by implementing conditional authentication within your application code which will allow you to bypass authentication for specific paths. For example, you could configure the middleware to skip authentication for certain routes. Something like this-
example-
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Bypass authentication for Swagger endpoint
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"))
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            return;
        }

        // Proceed with normal auth middleware
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not authenticated");
        }
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

This will check if the incoming request path starts with /swagger and skips authentication if it does. Otherwise, it proceeds with the normal authentication process.
References:

Authentication and authorization in Azure Container Apps
Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service and Azure Functions

